# Trying to control simultaneous Carousels

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have 4 carousels in total. But only 2 are visible at any one time. These 2 are also controlled by the same controls. Most of the functionality is working except for the second button not displaying the second pair of carousels:

http://jsfiddle.net/Stref/z6wyhfev/

I believe there is something wrong with:

```
$('.toggleCar').click(function(){
var CarWrapperName=$(this).attr('data-for');
    $('.Car-toggle').hide();
    $('#'+CarWrapperName).show();
});

//Hide All Toggles and Show Default
$('.Car-toggle').hide();
$('#Car-1').show();
$('#Floors-Words-Car').show();
```

Comment: Also, CSS isn't working on js fiddle?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/z6wyhfev/2/
The javascript should be modified as follows.
Some changes are in html and css also.

```
    $('.toggleCar').click(function(){
var CarWrapperName=$(this).attr('data-for');
    $('.Car-toggle').hide();
    $('#'+CarWrapperName).show();
    if(CarWrapperName=="Car-1"){
        $('#Floors-Words-Car').show();
        $('#Space-Words-Car').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#Floors-Words-Car').hide();
        $('#Space-Words-Car').show();
    }
});

//Hide All Toggles and Show Default
$('.Car-toggle').hide();
$('#Car-1').show();
$('#Floors-Words-Car').show();
$('#Space-Words-Car').hide();
```